# Page occasionally does not load from cy.visit()

Tags: javascript, cypress

After a few it block, cy.visit() stop attempting to load the url and the test fails due to assertions regarding page loading. Has anyone come across this and has any solution to this.

my code is something like this:

```
    describe('Check stuff', () => {
  const password = Cypress.env('PASSWORD');
  const user1 = Cypress.env('USERS_US')['USER1']['USERNAME']

    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.login(user1, password);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      // Log out
      cy.visit('/logout');
    });

    it('check1', () => {
    // Direct to report page
      cy.visit('url1');
      cy.url().should('contain', 'url1');

      });

    it('check2', () => {
    // Direct to report page
      cy.visit('url2');
      cy.url().should('contain', 'url2');

      });

    it('check3', () => {
    // Direct to report page
      cy.visit('url3');
      cy.url().should('contain', 'url3');

      });

    it('check4', () => {
    // Direct to report page
      cy.visit('url4');
      cy.url().should('contain', 'url4');

      });
    it('check5', () => {
    // Direct to report page
      cy.visit('url5');
      cy.url().should('contain', 'url5');

      });
});
```

Comment: It's kind of hard to say what could it be the issue. If you provide more information like code it would be helpful.

Comment: I have updated the question with some sample code. once it gets to the check4 and check5 it stops trying the visit